# Where can I rent a car in Belgium with under 1 year of having a driving license

Tags: car-rentals

I'm flying to Belgium in a few months and noticed that all the car rental companies require you to have a minimum of 1 year driving license.

I am 32 years old, but have my driving license for only 3 months.

Is there any company in Belgium (Ideally that has a branch in the airport) that I can rent a car from them that doesn't have that minimum 1 year requirement?

Comment: Probably not if it's the law in Belgium.

Comment: @Max this kind of requirement is common in many countries as a *company policy*. Is there any particular reason to think it's a law in Belgium?

Comment: Yea, I'm pretty sure its not a 'Law' ...  its a policy per each company.. some wants 1 year, some wants 2 years.. and I guess there is probably at least 1 company that doesn't need that requirement (though probably charges more... which is ok by me)

Comment: It may be a condition of the insurance. The rental company has to provide the minimum insurance required by law.

Comment: The easiest solution to a problem is to choose not to have it in the first place. Do you really need a car for what you intend to do in Belgium?

Comment: @KristvanBesien Yes. Otherwise I wouldn't have even bothered getting into a car renting rabbit hole

Comment: @Zolo: you should ask directly to them. Sometime they make "exceptions" (often as "extra fee"). OTOH it depends on their insurance policy and they would not risk. (OTOH 3 months and driving in a foreign country on a random car may not seems safe for them, OTOH I think you are able to do parking much better then us)